# Trigger to update Owner not working

Tags: apex, trigger

this trigger to update the owner of a custom object isn't working, but I'm not sure why.  It needs to get the owner ID from a related user on the parent object.

```
trigger UserDataRequestTrigger on User_Data_Request__c (after insert) {

    List<User_Data_Request__c> UDRupdate = new List<User_Data_Request__c>();

    //pull in the values ID, manager ID, from record     
    List<User_Data_Request__c> UDRList = [select id, User_Automation__r.User__r.Id 
                                            from User_Data_Request__c
                                            where id in:  trigger.newmap.keyset()];

    //Loop through the contacts 
    for(User_Data_Request__c udr: UDRupdate){
        udr.OwnerID = udr.Existing_User__r.User__r.Id;
        UDRupdate.add(udr);
    }
    //If there is anything in the list, commit the changes to the DB 
    if(UDRupdate.size() > 0){
        update UDRupdate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you come across any error and make sure that your query is pulling values by writing a debug log.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use UDRList in the for loop. You are using UDRupdate but this is just an empty list. The User_Data_Request__c from the DB are saved in UDRList.

```
for(User_Data_Request__c udr: UDList){
    udr.OwnerID = udr.Existing_User__r.User__r.Id;
    UDRupdate.add(udr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these changes and let me know if this worked..

```
trigger UserDataRequestTrigger on User_Data_Request__c (after insert) {

List<User_Data_Request__c> UDRupdate = new List<User_Data_Request__c>();

//pull in the values ID, manager ID, from record     
//Updated the query to call the user id of existing user ...
List<User_Data_Request__c> UDRList = [select id, User_Automation__r.User__r.Id,Existing_User__r.User__r.Id 
                                        from User_Data_Request__c
                                        where id in:  trigger.newmap.keyset()];

//Loop through the contacts 
//Use of correct list ...
for(User_Data_Request__c udr: UDRList){
    udr.OwnerID = udr.Existing_User__r.User__r.Id;
    UDRupdate.add(udr);
}
//If there is anything in the list, commit the changes to the DB 
if(UDRupdate.size() > 0){
    update UDRupdate;
}
}
```